# kern.log consuming all my disk space(entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe)

Tags: kernel, filesystem, log, syslog, syslinux

I get a warning that I am running out of disk space.  I find that it is the syslogs, especially the kern.log(s) that are eating up disk.
It seems like my system is writing message over and over hundreds of times per minutes
I have line repeted in the file  log : entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe
any one know cause of this problem and how can i fix it .

thank you for your helps,

Comment: Hello. Please provide information about both your Ubuntu and Kernel version. Include output of `lsb-release -a` and `uname -a`. Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu  version :  22.04.1 LTS and kernel version: 5.15.0-52-generic

Comment: Also please include complete log output for the last minute or so .. In your post please, use the edit function.

Comment: Also please (in your post) give some context. When did this begin, and did something special happen on that occasion (new apps, new settings etc)?

Comment: That message is typically at the end of a call trace dump and provides no information as to what caused a call trace to be logged in the first place. To be able to help, we need all the information @ArturMeinild has asked for.